# Convert RegExp back to string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, indexing

I want to get my RegExp back as a string:

```
var test = RegExp("[a-z]{5}");
// want "[a-z]{5}" or even "/[a-z]{5}/" as a string
```

Using `toString` returns `"[object Object]"`

**More context:**

I have some stored RegExp patters I'm using to search a very large string. There are certain indices where the match shouldn't happen, determined by a fairly complex mathematical equation. After running a `string.replace(test, function)` I test the matched index against my equation, and if is an index that is not allowed, I want to re-run the replace, except starting at the next index. Since `string.replace` in javascript doesn't take an index parameter, I want to take my RegExp, and prepend `*{firstIndexWeFound + 1}` to compensate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `source` property:

```
var test = RegExp("[a-z]{5}");
var pattern = test.source; // returns "[a-z]{5}"
```

Comment: On a side note, if you want the full expression (i.e., with slashes and modifiers), you use `test.toString();` . . . not sure why you'd be getting `"[object Object]"` . . .

Answer (score 1):

Rather than tweaking the regex and making a new regex after every match it is better to set the [`lastIndex property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of your regex:

```
test.lastIndex = someIndex;
```

As per documentation:

> The lastIndex is a read/write integer property of regular expressions
>   that specifies the index at which to start the next match.

PS: This property is set only if the regular expression used the "g" flag to indicate a global search.

Comment: This is very good! However, I don't want to waste any more power than I have to matching every place the string matches (could be thousands of places in my case.) Is there a way to break out of replace from within the replace function? So once I get a match I like, I can stop the "g" global search?